# Access text currently selected in outlook 2007

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, outlook-2007, outlook-addin

I'd like to create C# outlook addin to automate a process of adding mail fragments as comments in my bug tracking system (Jira).

To create the comment I need to extract currently selected text.
I manage to do that in a tricky way for email window (following [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsto/thread/505e309a-dfe5-407c-ad6b-929178944d3b) article).
But I didn't find any way to access the current selection in the preview window.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you see Jira's built-in email-to-comment functionality? http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/v3.13/issue_creation_email.html

Comment: It doesn't work to well with outlook way of replaying to emails. Basically you end up having comments that duplicates whole conversation

Comment: On the other hand lot of clients don't cc mail2jira gatways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there is no exposed way to access selected text in the reading pane of Outlook 2007.

The most reasonable [solution](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/conversation.aspx?messageid=31435029&threadid=31416437) I've found is to send "CTRL-c" and read the text that was copied. But it doesn't always work as the mail viewer in reading pane has to be selected which isn't always true.